# How to compatible and fix screen size for all devices in cordova

Tags: cordova

When I run my Cordova application, it is bigger than screen and it shows scrolls.

Is there any solution to resize/fix screen size in all screen?

Answer (score 1):

Have you set a meta tag in you index.html file?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
```

Comment: Yes I tires this meta tag,
But the content is bigger than my screen I need something like dynamic scale!